# How to append a symbol before last 6 digit of a file name in batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a Batch script for following tasks:

- **Task 1:** Find a specific name (.txt.) and replace with specific name(.txt_) in all the file name in a folder.
- **Task 2:** Append a symbol(_) before last 6 digit of a file name in batch script.

  As IF:
  Test.txt.20210808654321

  To be:
  Test.txt_20210808_654321

I have created a script for **Task 1** and it is working.

Script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "replace=.txt_"
set "find=.txt."

for %%i in ("C:\Script test\*.*") do (
   set name=%%~ni
   set ext=%%~xi
   ren "%%i" "!name:%find%=%replace%!!ext!"
)
pause
```

But I am struck in Task 2 (= Append a symbol(_) before last 6 digit of a file name).

Any help to finish it?

Comment: Check out [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, without the need to use 'find' and 'replace' strings:

```sh
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe
 ".":"*.txt.??????????????" 2^>NUL') Do @(Set "}=%%~xG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For /F Delims^=. %%H In ("!}:~,9!_!}:~9!"
) Do @EndLocal & Ren "%%G" "%%~nG_%%~H")
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Please let me know how can i do Task 2: Append a symbol(_) before last 6 digit of a file name in batch script. i tried this 'ren *.txt_??????????????* *.txt_????????_??????*'

Comment: The script I have provided above already does that @Newuser, as there are exactly fifteen characters in the existing extension, it places an underscore after the first nine of them. If you have not told us the truth about your extension and it does not really contain a date and time stamp, `.yyyyMMddhhmmss`, _(which would be logical)_, and you really wanted to place the underscore six from the end, then change the `9` digits to `-6`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I have tried with minus 6 but still it doesn't work.
Let me know if i have to change anything below.

Folder name: C:\Script test

Files in folder:
Test0.txt.20210901061000
Test1.txt.20210901061000
Test2.txt.20210901061000

Script in .bat file:

'@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& C:\Script test ".":"*.txt.??????????????" 2^>NUL') 
Do @(Set "}=%%~xG"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For /F Delims^=. %%H In ("!}:~,-6!_!}:~-6!") 
Do @EndLocal & Ren "%%G" "%%~nG_%%~H")'

Comment: Well you've either done something wrong, or you have been untruthful with the question parameters, because it 100% does work, using `!}:~,-6!_!}:~-6!` I am not attempting to read code in the comments, so please post the code you say is not working in you question area, explain how it is failing to work, provide the fully qualified file paths before and after, and if necessary, remove the three `@` characters from the answer, and run the script directly from within a Command Prompt window, so that we can all see that for debugging purposes.